# How to solve $dy/dx = \frac{(3y^2+2x^2)}{ (xy)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got this problem in today's exam and I couldn't quite figure this out. The equation is $xy \, dy = (3y^2+2x^2) \, dx$, $M_y = 6y$ and $N_x = y$, they aren't equal so this equation is nowhere near exact, it doesn't look like I can do separable either? What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiplying both sides by $2y$ yields:
$$
2y\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{6y^2+4x^2}{x} = \left(\dfrac{6}{x}\right)y^2 + 4x
$$
Now let $v=y^2$. Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=2y\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. Substitution yields:
$$
\dfrac{dv}{dx} = \left(\dfrac{6}{x}\right)v + 4x \iff \dfrac{dv}{dx} - \left(\dfrac{6}{x}\right)v = 4x 
$$
which is a linear ODE that can be solved using the method of integrating factors.

Comment: Thanks Adriano for the edit. a + was dedicated to you before. :-)

Comment: @BabakS. No problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**General hint:**

This is an Homogenous equation of first order since you can write it as $$y'=f\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ Assume $u=\frac{y}{x},~~x\neq 0$ and solve the following OE instead: $$\frac{du}{f(u)-u}=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Here you see that if $x\ne 0$, then $$y'=\frac{x^2(3u^2+2)}{x^2u}=\frac{(3u^2+2)}{u}=f(u),~~~u=\frac{y}{x}$$

Comment: $\overbrace{\ddot\smile}^{}$

Comment: @amWhy: :D it seems to me like someone put the leafs of a banana on his head. :^D)

Comment: @amWhy: As far as I know, women wear it?

Comment: Hey, man, you made a calculating error, should be 3u^2 + 2 in the top right?